# Using XML Layouts with LibGDX

Tags: xml, user-interface, interface, libgdx

I am working on a GUI for a small app project that is built on LibGDX.  I was wondering, given that it is possible to add default Android interface components and layouts over the top of a LibGDX view programatically, is it possible to simply use full XML layouts as well?  In my particular case, this would be a far quicker way to go, with little reason to use the Scene2d.ui class if it is not necessary.

I haven't been able to get this to work, and don't particularly have a problem if I need to use LibGDX's interface building tools, but this route seems more pleasant to me.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a reason why you can't use XML layout on Android when you say that it is possible to add Android interface components over LibGDX view programatically.

I think that you can also use XML layouts, but your project will lose the big advantages of LibGDX - cross-platform and desktop development. Your project will be runnable only on Android. So i also recommend to use Scene2D ui.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use native GUI, but you can try to use its default scene2d ui. For me, build a UI framework by myself is a good choice.